# Model binding a form created from configurations in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages/MVC

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

In my database I have configured fields for a product:

Here is what the entity looks like:

**ProductField**
Id (PK)
ProductId (FK)
Label  (To be used as the field label)
Type  (Text, TextArea)

When the page loads I have a Page Model for my Product Entity which has a navigation property called Fields of type ProductField. In my razor syntax I am doing the following:

```
<form method="post">
    @{
        int i = 0;

        if (Model.Product.Fields.Count > 0)
        {
            @foreach (var field in Model.Product.Fields)
            {
                if (field.Type == "Text")
                {
                    <input id="txt_@i" type="text">
                }
                else if (field.Type == "Signature")
                {
                    <textarea id="txtArea_@i"></textarea>
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
</form>
```

The part that I am having trouble with is creating a ViewModel that can be posted to properly so I can access the value of each field and store it in the database.

There is another table in the database to store the value for each field:

**ProductFieldValue**
ProductFieldId (FK)
UserId (the Id of the user filling out the form)
Value  (value for that field)

What is the proper way to to model binding in a scenario like this using Razor Pages or MVC?

Answer (score 2):

To model binding with List of data in Razor Pages, you need to use `name` property to pass all data to backend.

In PageModel,declare List to store input data

```
[BindProperty]
public List<string> DataStored { get; set; }
```

In razor View

```
<form method="post">
@{
    int i = 0;

    if (Model.Product.Fields.Count > 0)
    {
        @foreach (var field in Model.Product.Fields)
        {
            if (field.Type == "Text")
            {
                <input type="text" id="txt_@i" class="items" name="DataStored[@i]" />

            }
            else if (field.Type == "Signature")
            {
                <textarea id="txtArea_@i" class="items" name="DataStored[@i]" ></textarea>

            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

If you use MVC,then accept List as action parameters.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(List<string> dataStored)
```

Comment: Got it, but at this point I just have a list of strings. How do I know what value is for what field so I can store into my ProductFieldValues and save?

Comment: I guess I could go by order if I'm careful that my sorting is accurate.